# Runtime Error 1004 while Range = String

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a long String out of various Letters and some variables

All variables are Strings.

```
pfad = t1 & tn & t2 & tn & t3 & kunde & t4 & datum & t5 & zeileStr
```

After pfad has been created, id like to have this String or in other words this sentence in an specific Cell. This Cell should be choosen by 2 variables ( Row and column).
Here my Code:

```
While z < 9            
BZ = zeile + 5

Range(AZ & BZ) = pfad  <<<<<<<<<< this is marked yellow, when im going to debug mode
z = z + 1
zeile = zeile + 1
zeileStr = CStr(zeile)
pfad = t1 & tn & t2 & tn & t3 & kunde & t4 & datum & t5 & zeileStr
Wend
```

Comment: If this is intended to go into AZ5:AZ13 then you need to put *AZ* into quotes. e.g. `Range("AZ" & BZ) = pfad`

Comment: What are `AZ` and `BZ`? Depending on the values stored in those variables, you will potentially need some formatting inside the `Range` assignment.

Comment: AZ is a String and BZ is a Integer.
They are going down a row and they should inserting 'pfad' in this row

Comment: I have to mention, you can use numbers to represent the Column, instead of using a string, with column letters.  If you have to go through a lot to do that.  Consider `.Cells(row, col)` where `row` and `col` are both `Long` type, (or integer, but preferably Long)

Comment: When i change it to "Cells(AZ,BZ) = pfad there is still the same failure

Comment: it needs to be `Cells(BZ, AZ)`.  BZ is for a number representation of the ROW, and AZ is for the column, and can usually accept either letters as a string or numbers, in variable form.  How are you getting the value for AZ?  can you post that also?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the assignment you are looking for.

```
Dim As Integer   'Long, preferable
Dim AZ As String
Dim pfad As String

Sheets("SheetName").Cells(BZ, AZ).Value = pfad
```

You will want to put that line after you've defined pfad instead of before it as well.

```
Do While z < 9            
    BZ = zeile + 5
    z = z + 1
    zeile = zeile + 1
    zeileStr = CStr(zeile)
    pfad = t1 & tn & t2 & tn & t3 & kunde & t4 & datum & t5 & zeileStr

    Sheets("SheetName").Cells(BZ, AZ).Value = pfad
Loop
```

**note:** Wend is used for backwards compatibility more now.  Using `Do While... Loop`

Comment: There is still the same failure. In Debugmode its marking the Sheets("")... line

Comment: How are you getting AZ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim AZ As Long 
Dim BZ As Long 
Dim pfad As String 
Dim zeile As Integer 
Dim zeileStr As String 
Dim z As Integer

tn = Range("B3")
kunde = Range("B4")
zeile = 2
AZ = 1
BZ = 0
zeileStr = CStr(zeile)
```

All  variables are defined or their values are i a cell.

When i used the Range() order, AZ was a String.